# VBA For Each paste returns formula in first loop of For Each and then values after that

Tags: excel, vba, foreach, paste

I am splitting one master workbook in to many others. I just want values pasted, however for the first filtered result in the For Each loop it copies formulas across, every other filteres result wihtin the loop returns values only (as desired). Is there an obvious reason for this?

Many thanks,

Stephen

```
Range("B1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Combined Data")
Set rData = .Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 13).End(xlUp))
.Columns(.Columns.Count).Clear
.Range(.Cells(2, 6), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp)).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=.Cells(1, .Columns.Count), Unique:=True

For Each rfl In .Range(.Cells(2, .Columns.Count), .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).End(xlUp))
state = rfl.Text

Set wsNew = Workbooks.Add
sfilename = "Monday" & " " & state & " - Engagement" & ".xlsx"


ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs PATH & "\" & sfilename


Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ws.Activate
rData.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=state


rData.Copy
Windows(sfilename).Activate
ActiveSheet.Paste

ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
Next rfl
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End With

ws.Columns(Columns.Count).ClearContents
rData.AutoFilter
```

Comment: `Paste` doesn't paste values... it pastes everything.

Comment: @BigBen Thanks, I can certainly insert a paste special but what I'm confused by is why is it posting values for 28 of the new workbooks and formulas for the first one?